# Running docker container with my own privileges

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to contain the dependencies of a complex application within a docker container, but let it operate on my own files, without having conflicting UIDs at the end. In essence, I want to run something like:

```
docker run \
    --rm \
    --volume $HOME/playbook:/playbook --workdir /playbook \
    --user $(id --user) \
    container_image
```

However, this fails because the application expects the provided UID to correspond to a username:

```
getpwuid(): uid not found: 1000
```

I ended up putting this in the `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN \
    for uid in seq 1000 1010; do \
        adduser --home /tmp/user_$uid --uid $uid user_$uid; \
    done
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Another solution might be to set up a directory server. Unless you have some very specific requirements LDAP is probably the most sensible option.

Comment: User namespace can be an option.Currently username space is available at daemon level, i think there is plan to add it at container level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something a little more portable, you could mount the /etc/passwd and /etc/group files into the container as read-only files:

```
docker run \
    --rm \
    --volume $HOME/playbook:/playbook --workdir /playbook \
    --user $(id --user) \
    --volume /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro \
    --volume /etc/group:/etc/group:ro \
    container_image
```

Two downsides are if the container expects it's own usernames to be defined, and file permissions from the image may have the wrong or missing user/group definitions on them.